# you are not authorized to set the license key unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

How can I fix this error? The license key is correct, keystore is entered.

[image]

I entered the license key first in the project dashboard in the In-app purchase (IAP) settings field on the Project setting tab

[image]

and here enter license key:

[image]

Comment: If it is configured already in the project and via this other wizard .. do you still need to configure it via the player settings then?